# Laravelのインストールについての質問

Tags: laravel

#### 解決したいこと

Laravelをインストールしようとしているのですが、スクショのような表示が出てしまいインストールすることが出来ません。

どのようにしたらインストール出来るのでしょうか？どなたか分かる方教えてください。

[image: スクリーンショット 2021-10-12 211310.png]

#### 自分で試したこと

自分でググってみて、`$ composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.5 laravel_project` などの別のコマンドでインストールしようとしたのですが、こちらの方法でもうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 「こちらの方法でもうまくいきませんでした」とありますが、どのようにうまくいかなかったのでしょうか？スクショの内容についても、インストーラーは問題なくインストールできているようにみえ、何が問題なのかわかりません。つづけて`laravel new`をしようとするとコマンドがみつからないと怒られる、などというならともかく……。インストールはドキュメントどおりでいいはずですが、どこに問題が発生しているか確認しなおしてみてください。

Comment: laravel newで起動出来ました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

hinaloe さんにコメント欄でアドバイス頂いた通り `laravel new` を実行した結果、laravel を起動することができました。